# JAVA: Copying a ZipFile to ZipOutputStream with multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot server. I am making an endpoint which copies a zip file, add some files to it and return it in the response OutputStream. It works fine but when I make two requests at the same times, one works but the others fail with `invalid entry CRC (expected 0x582bfb02 but got 0xe4d4b754)`.

This is the piece of code which fails

```
ZipFile templateFile = new ZipFile(new File(dir_to_zip_file));
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> templateFileEntries = templateFile.entries();

while (templateFileEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry entry = templateFileEntries.nextElement();
    if (!skippableFiles.contains(entry.getName())) {
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            copy(templateFile.getInputStream(entry), zipOutputStream);
        }
        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

I have read that zlib is not always thread-safe, does somebody know how I have to change this code to make it work?

Comment: Any output to a stream is inherently sequential, and therefore not parallel.  Remove the multi-threading part for the creation of the stream.

Comment: Two separate requests should be sharing anything. Are you perhaps sharing temp. files? Fields? Not enough code for us to identify a problem, since the code you do show should have no issues.

Comment: Each request shared the zip file which has to be copied. I have added more information on the code

Comment: If two requests share the same file, how do you guarantee the correctness of the data's lifespan?

Comment: Because the file is read-only (nobody modifies the file)